# loading an image from a package in Java (JFrame)

Tags: java, image, jframe, embedded-resource

I'm having a problem loading an image from a package I created in the project that was set to contain images. I have to write the whole picture location in the computer instead of just the package that contains it. I've tried several things but nothing seems to work... 
This is the command I use to load the image:

```
searchBar = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project\\src\\Images\\search.jpg"));
```

"Images" is a package in my project, this works, but when I try loading the image without the "C:\..." only with the "\Images..."  it doesn't , so i have to change it every time i open this project in another computer.
Hopefully one of u has the answer for me, thanks in advance for any answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageIO.read(YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream('path/search.jpg'));` Path probably is `/Images/`.

You can get the URL by `getResource` but there is not much use here.

Comment: i've tried it and it works! thank u so much! have a great week :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to read image .

```
ImageIO.read(Testing.class.getResource("/Images/search.png"));
```

You should have `Images` as your package in `src`